# @csrf vs {{ csrf_field() }}

Tags: laravel

Estoy revisando un código que utiliza `{{ csrf_field() }}` para el envío de los formularios, yo utilzó `@csrf` estoy buscando información en internet y por lo que entendí tienen la misma función, ¿es así? me gustaría estar seguro antes de cambiarlo.

Sería igual si se aplica de esta manera?

```
<form action="{{ route('miruta') }}" method="POST">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>

<form action="{{ route('miruta') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Si, es lo mismo. csrf te crea un campo en el form para caundo l oenvies en el backend usando un tag de blade template, el otro llama a una funcion que hace exactamente lo mismo pero de otra forma, siempre queda mas limpio csrf

Comment: Muchas gracias @josanangel seguiré utilizando `@csrf`

Answer (score 1):

Simplemente es lo mismo, para comprender un poco más de que va
te muestro la funcionalidad del helper

```
/**
 * Compile the CSRF statements into valid PHP.
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function compileCsrf()
{
    return '<?php echo csrf_field(); ?>';
}
```

A su vez este llama otro helper csrf_field() para crear el input html

```
    /**
     * Generate a CSRF token form field.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\HtmlString
     */

function csrf_field()
{
    return new HtmlString('<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="'.csrf_token().'">');
}
```

Este llama un ultimo helper csrf_token() para obtener el token de la sesion actual

```
/**
 * Get the CSRF token value.
 *
 * @return string
 *
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 */
function csrf_token()
{
    $session = app('session');

    if (isset($session)) {
        return $session->token();
    }

    throw new RuntimeException('Application session store not set.');
}
```

Con esto tambien podemos hacerlo directamente llamando el valor del token

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

teniendo 3 formas de hacer lo mismo yo, en lo personal utilizo @csrf para tener un código más limpio debido a que es una sintaxis más corta